# How to properly diagnose computer shutdown when editing video, with no system logs?

Tags: windows-10, video, shutdown, video-editing

This has been a problem for years. When I render or even just edit video (Specifically in DaVinci Resolve, no problem with Premiere) my computer will shut off. This is a Windows 10 machine, and nothing is visible in Event Viewer (just normal logs- and then suddenly system boot up logs from when I hit the power button)

So I have no trail to even follow. No errors, just me editing one minute, and then black screen. It's as though the power got yanked from the computer.

I decided to open a project and try rendering it, and pop up all the system logs I could and film it with my phone. This is the screen the second before it turned off

[image: screenshot of system logs]

Nothing seems to be too odd to me. What on earth do I do to figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a hardware issue, either the GPU or the PSU. Let me explain how I come to think so:

- Nothing **at all** in the logs is odd even for Windows
- DaVinci uses the GPU intensively, Premiere does not
- The GPU is the single biggest power consumer (thus the PSU angle)
- On disassertion of the power good signal, the MB will shut down the PSU hard (an the OS won't know about it)
- GPUs can get very hot on DaVinci use and may shut down hard blocking the PCIe bus.

To verify this is the issue, you could stop GPU use by DaVinci - either via configuration or by temporarily replacing it with a less powerfull one, that doesn't support DaVinci GPU rendering.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to buy a new GPU to diagnose the problem, but based on what your saying that might end up being what I have to try! Thanks.

Comment: A cheap old GPU should be best - nothing in your stockpile? Or couldn't you configure DaVinci not to use CUDA rendering?